# Объединение одинаковых ячеек скриптом Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

У меня есть таблица, с столбцами `partner`, `id`, `email`, `status`, `type`, `group`, `details`. Есть повторяющиеся значения в столбцах `id`, `email`, `status`, `type`, `group`.

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

| partner | id        | email               | status | type | group | details              |
|---------|-----------|---------------------|--------|------|-------|----------------------|
| YESTKBW | Wednesday | wednesday@gmail.com | YES    | 0    | 11    | kgplqolgbmdxenwpehyn |
| ZBSDCUY | Wednesday | wednesday@gmail.com | YES    | 0    | 11    | upujkpekm tmqfzpca   |
| RBGBHNK | Wednesday | wednesday@gmail.com | YES    | 0    | 11    | iky k gtlffdyukngwlo |
| UXJGHLW | Saturday  | saturday@gmail.com  | NO     | 0    | 11    | mjdmodggygxkydxifxny |
| UZHNECM | Friday    | friday@gmail.com    | YES    | 1    | 22    | wpboajbemueskbuyjqeg |
| XACTUOK | Tuesday   | tuesday@gmail.com   | NO     | 2    | 33    | rxnwkpmegng bobjdqlz |
| EIOBZXS | Tuesday   | tuesday@gmail.com   | NO     | 2    | 33    | rwqxxwoeanxqsbpbwx j |
```

Я пытаюсь сделать скрипт, который будет при одинаковых идущих подряд значениях id, объединять ячейки в столбцах `id`, `email`, `status`, `type`, `group`. Значения `partner` и `details` трогать не нужно.

Пример того, что должно получиться

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

| partner | id        | email               | status | type | group | details              |
|---------|-----------|---------------------|--------|------|-------|----------------------|
| YESTKBW | Wednesday | wednesday@gmail.com | YES    | 0    | 11    | kgplqolgbmdxenwpehyn |
| ZBSDCUY |           |                     |        |      |       | upujkpekm tmqfzpca   |
| RBGBHNK |           |                     |        |      |       | iky k gtlffdyukngwlo |
| UXJGHLW | Saturday  | saturday@gmail.com  | NO     | 0    | 11    | mjdmodggygxkydxifxny |
| UZHNECM | Friday    | friday@gmail.com    | YES    | 1    | 22    | wpboajbemueskbuyjqeg |
| XACTUOK | Tuesday   | tuesday@gmail.com   | NO     | 2    | 33    | rxnwkpmegng bobjdqlz |
| EIOBZXS |           |                     |        |      |       | rwqxxwoeanxqsbpbwx j |
```

Я понимаю, что необходимо использовать метод [`mergeVertically()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#mergeVertically()) класса [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), но у меня недостаточно опыта, чтобы решить эту задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ок. Этот вопрос ничем существенным не отличается от этого [Hide rows with criteria on click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39058303/1393023).

Положим, что у нас есть какой-то метод объединения ячеек:

```
function verticallyMerger(sheet, blocks){
  /*
  {
  columns: [],
  rows: [[index, count],[index, count]]
  }
  */
  for (var i = 0; i < blocks.rows.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < blocks.columns.length; j++){
      sheet.getRange(blocks.rows[i][0], blocks.columns[j], blocks.rows[i][1]).mergeVertically();
    }
  }
  return sheet;
}
```

Все довольно прозрачно:

- перебираем настройки
- применяем по очереди

Осталось добавить более-менее полезный конструктор блоков настройки. Например,

```
function blockBilder(sheet, initialBlocks){
  var blocks = initialBlocks;
  blocks.rows = [];
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, blocks.mergerColumn, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var isNew = true;
  var prevVal;
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if(prevVal === values[i][0]){
      if(isNew){
        blocks.rows.push([i , 2]);
        isNew = false;
      } else {
        blocks.rows[blocks.rows.length - 1][1]++;
      }
    } else {
      prevVal = values[i][0];
      isNew = true;
    }
  }
  return blocks;
}
```

Тут, конечно, без пояснения не все очевидно. `initialBlocks` обязан представлять объект вроде такого

```
{
  mergerColumn : 2
}
```

`mergerColumn` - номер колонки, на основе которой будет производиться вывод о необходимости объединения

Теперь это можно запустить

```
function run(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var blocks = blockBilder(sheet, {mergerColumn : 2, columns: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]});
  verticallyMerger(sheet, blocks);
}
```

В `blocks` добалено еще одно свойство, которое необходимо для `verticallyMerger` - это `columns`. Оно содержит массив, в котором перечислены колонки для объединения.

[Тут](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/844c9c135233f37ce985a88c036e8644) можно получить копию рабочего примера и код полностью.

Comment: Спасибо. Как-раз то, что нужно!

Comment: Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как решение.

Comment: Скрипт перестал работать. Выдает ошибку: TypeError: Cannot read property "rows" from undefined. (line 8, file "Code") Не скажете, в чем причина?

Comment: @MaksymKatsovets, посмотрите, что вы передаетет в качестве `block` или `initialBlocks`.